# Going to specific instance of element class

Tags: javascript, html

I can use the following to create a indexed list of each instance of a particular item in a class.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("page");
```

I can use the following to direct users to a particular id:

```
function CalledBySelectBox(value)
    {
    document.getElementById(value).scrollIntoView();
    }
```

However, the elements I want to direct users to are not uniquely identified with Id's. How do I modify the second snippet above, to direct users to a particular instance/occurrence of x in the first snippet. Or to put it differently, how do I direct them to a particular instance of the class.

If its helpful, here is some sample html:

```
Some text of unknown length full of random tags and what have you.<span class="page">104</span> A bunch more text but we don't know how much and full of other tags.<span class="page">105</span> Some text of unknown length full of random tags and what have you <span class="page">106</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
function ScrollToPage( page_num )
{
    document.getElementsByClassName( 'page' )[ page_num ].scrollIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What `getElementsByClassName(className)` gives you is an array of elements, what `document.getElementById(id)` gives you is a single element.  To scroll to an indexed element in the array you get, just call `scrollIntoView()` on that element.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("page");
x[5].scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Both this answer and Paulpro's answer worked. But this was easier for me to read/understand.

Thank you both.

Comment: @COMisHARD You're welcome. Please accept Jason's answer by clicking the checkmark beside it; since it helped you the most.